# Fragment List view replace

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

When i replace fragment Listview place fragment Listview
I had trouble this in photo but i can't fix it .
i need to fix it,plz.
[UI_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7r9I.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s402l.png)

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String[] titel = {"asdasd", "asda", "bdfg", "asdqweqwe"};
        int idimg = R.mipmap.icon_main_list;
        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), titel, idimg);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Anmalz anmalz=new Anmalz();
                Main_List_Fragment main_list_fragment=new Main_List_Fragment();
               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, anmalz);
                fragmentTransaction.remove(main_list_fragment).commit();

                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onCreateView()` to -

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_list, container, false);
    }
```

Also, in `onListItemClick()`, you should not remove/replace the same fragment again and again. You should just refresh the list adapter.

Comment: how i can refresh the list adapter ?

Comment: By using this method - `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Where used this method?? in switch ?

Comment: Yes. that's where you want I guess.